# Exclude certain items on result page in LOW SEARCH

Tags: low-search

Does anyone know a way to exclude some results on the result page of LOW SEARCH?
I have been looking everywhere but I cannot find the answer.
I understand I must add a SEARCH form on the resultpage, but do not know what next to do.

My client wants to 'hold' certain results AFTER they made a search and  then save the results for later use.

So filter in results, so to speak.

Thanks a lot for a hint.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify further?  You can't find the info in the documentation regarding excluding results, or it's not providing the functionality you need?
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters

Comment: Yes, I 'll do my best. Wanted exampel situation: client performs a search and gets 10 results (entrees), they decide to keep (=save) only 5 for later. So, I must make a checkbox there that excludes some in a new search on that result page. I do not know how to do that, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I fully accepted Low's answer I add another one.

This is how I filter now in search results, *(and it is actuelly just what I was looking for. Maybe I did not ask clear enough, sorry about that)*

I added to my seach:form

```
require_all="search:{url_title}"
```

made sure all channels have unique url_titles by adding a prefix in the channel preferences,

and made a checkbox like this:

```
<label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="search:url_title[]" value="{url_title}"
            {if "{option:value}" IN ({low_search_search:url_title})} checked="checked"{/if} />
            Save 
</label>
```

Now, when ticking some boxes in the searchform only those results return. I tested it, and it works well enough for me to filter in a simple way within search results.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question in your post, about excluding entries from search results, I can say this: do it like you would with a regular channel:entries tag, so using a parameter like `entry_id="not 1|2|3"`, where 1, 2 and 3 are the entry IDs you want to exclude. You can do that using status, categories, or any parameter, as per the native EE parameters themselves.

If you want to make this dynamic, then you need to feed those entries to the entry_id parameter in your form somehow, so you end up with a (hidden) input field that looks something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="not 1|2|3">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Low. I am not an expert, but could this be done with javascript that 'listens' to status-change of checkboxes of each entree that the user wants to include in the fine search? Or are there other methodes? Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Sure. As long as you make sure the form submits the value `not 1|2|3` you should be fine. The way you implement it is up to you.